# Run a non main class from Spring Boot jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, classpath

I have a spring boot jar file and inside it a manifest file as below

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: myApp
Implementation-Version: 0.1
Built-By: me
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.myApp
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.0.0.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.myApp.smartlight.BootMongoDBApp
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.1
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_151
```

And inside it is a class file named `com.myApp.initiate.Initiator` *(packaged under BOOT-INF/classes folder inside the jar)*. I am trying to run Initiator class from command line on Windows machine as below

`java -cp myApp.jar com.myApp.initiate.Initiator`

but no luck. I also tried mentioning classpath in the above command as

`java -cp "myApp.jar;BOOT-INF/*" com.myApp.initiate.Initiator`

but it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

**Initiator.java**

```
package com.myApp.initiate.Initiator;

public class Initiator {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        System.out.print("hello");
    }
}
```

**Update :**

`Initiator` class was packaged under BOOT-INF/classes folder. When I copied it at the jar root and tried below command it worked

```
myApp.jar
|
|--org
|--BOOT-INF
|--META-INF
|--Initiator.class
```

```
java -cp myApp.jar Initiator
hello
```

**Update:** *Thanks to @Strelok for the hints, I managed to get it working thru*

`java -cp myApp.jar -Dloader.main=com.myApp.initiate.Initiator org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`

Comment: Can you add somepeace of code so we can see what your application do?

Comment: Why do you think that is *still doesn't work*? BTW use only lower case character in package names

Comment: @Jens It is just a regular Spring Boot application which runs fine through command line. Ans Initiator class just prints "hello" for now nothing more. I run the above mentioned commands from the same directory as the jar file.

Comment: Where is it a spring-boot app. Where is the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation?

Answer (score 4):

Specify the class path, and loader.main, and the springboot launcher, it works as qwerty suggested:

```
java -cp myApp.jar -Dloader.main=com.myApp.initiate.Initiator org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Comment: Very helpful to not have to change the existing manifest, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Standard way to run a Spring Boot app jar is with

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

To run a different class you need to switch to using the `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher` and add the `loader.main` property to you command line to choose a different class.

So you manifest must contain:

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Then on the command line:

```
java -jar myApp.jar -Dloader.main=com.myApp.initiate.Initiator
```

Have a look at the docs as well for more information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features

Comment: The jar runs fine through the above command. I want to run a different class file (Initiator) before I run my Spring boot app. You may check the manifest entries mentioned in OP as what I am trying to run is not a main class/start class.

Comment: @qwerty have a look at my updated answer. I missed the fact that your `Start-Class` was a different one in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the update. ```java -jar``` will run the Spring Boot jar...which I don't want in my case. I am just trying to RUN a CLASS FILE which lies inside that jar at mentioned folder.

Comment: Read carefully. You need to switch to PropertiesLauncher and specify an alternative class with `-Dloader.main`

Comment: I managed to get it working thru : ```java -cp myApp.jar -Dloader.main=com.myApp.initiate.Initiator org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher```