# How to specify an alternative main class in spring boot using bootBuildImage and packeto

Tags: spring-boot, paketo

When calling the spring boot plugin bootBuildImage task in gradle, a docker image is created using packeto. It starts the main class specified in the springBoot plugin. Below you can find an excerpt of the build.gradle file.

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = 'MyMainApp'
}


bootBuildImage {
    imageName = "$docker_repo/${project.name}"
}
```

When calling `docker run`, docker will run a container starting `MyMainApp`.

However, I want to run an alternative main class, using the same docker image. I tried the following:

- specifying `-Dloader.main=MyOtherApp` as the cmd in `docker run`
- specifying `-Dloader.main=MyOtherApp` in the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable
- specifying `LOADER_MAIN=MyOtherApp` as an environment variable

None of those options start `MyOtherApp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image created by Buildpacks provides some helpful tools for launching your application. While this is nice, overriding the default start command isn't as easy as just specifying a new command to `docker run`.

All of the facilities provided by Buildpacks for [starting up various processes in an image are described in the docs](https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/).

I'm guessing here a bit, but it sounds like you want to run your own custom process (not the process detected by the buildpack), so try [this one here](https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/#user-provided-shell-process).

> You can even override the buildpack-defined process types:
>
> ```
> docker run --rm --entrypoint launcher -it multi-process-app bash
> docker run --rm --entrypoint launcher -it multi-process-app echo hello "$WORLD" # $WORLD is evaluated on the host machine
> docker run --rm --entrypoint launcher -it multi-process-app echo hello '$WORLD' # $WORLD is evaluated in the container after profile scripts are sourced
> ```

Java should be on the path, so you can run `java -Dloader.main=MyOtherApp org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class#using-cli

---

Alternatively, you could change your app to use PropetiesLoader by default & rebuild your image. The buildpack is just pulling the launcher for the start command out of the MANIFEST.MF file. You need to use PropertiesLauncher though as that is what supports `loader.main`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66367534/1585136.